# jquery IE fails to load into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

My index.html page has a `<div id="contentarea"> </div>` where i need to load the data from external *.html files located in: content folder. As an example I created two files in the content folder:

```
content/aboutus.html
content/contactus.html
```

To load the data i use the jquery on hashchange trigger.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul class="navigationList">
                <a href="#aboutus"><li>about us</li></a>
                <a href="#contactus"><li>contact us</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
<div id="contentarea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the loader.js file i got a very simple script to load data into the `contentarea` div.

```
var href='';
 $(window).on('hashchange', function(){
    href = window.location.hash.substr(1) +".html";
    $('#contentarea').load('content/'+href +" #contentarea > *");
 });
```

I successfully tested it in Firefox and Safari until i got to Internet Explorer. IE just ignores completely the `$('#contentarea').load();`.

I have been at this for a while now but it appears that without external help i will be stuck forever.

To remedy the situation i wrote the code to detect the IE.

```
var href = '';
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');

 $(window).on('hashchange', function(){
    href = window.location.hash.substr(1) +".html";

    if (msie > 0  || edge >0 || trident > 0){
         //perform the load in IE working code should go in here
         alert( "Load was performed." );
    }
    else{
        $('#contentarea').load('content/'+href +" #contentarea > *");
    }
 });
```

I looked through forum posts but could not figure out how to fix the problem.
Would someone please help me out how to load the data into the div in Internet Explorer? Would the same code work in all IE versions?

Comment: What version of IE, what version of jQuery? jQuery 2.x doesn't support old versions of IE.

Comment: Do you get the alert?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: I am using IE11. The jquery is 3.1.0. I did not see any errors in the console during the execution. the alert is working and i get it each time i click on the button.